# GitHub Actions fails to access secrets

Tags: docker, github-actions

I have set up GitHub Actions to publish "nightly" Docker images on merged pull requests.

The problem I'm facing right now is that the step "Login to Docker Hub" keeps failing with `Error: Username and password required`. I changed only the trigger and job condition and can't imagine that this is the cause of the problem.

Is it possible that secrets are not available when the trigger looks like this:

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - closed
    branches:
      - dev
```

Yesterday everything worked, and I can see that the token was used the last time "Feb 28, 2024   11:29:25"

Full workflow file:

```yaml
name: Publish Docker nightly image

on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - closed
    branches:
      - dev

jobs:
  push_to_registry:
    name: Push Docker image to Docker Hub
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.repository == 'OpenHausIO/backend' && github.event.pull_request.merged == true
    steps:
      - name: Check out the repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Use Node.js 18.x
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: 18.x
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm run build  
      
      - name: Log in to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v3.0.0
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}
      
      - name: Extract metadata (tags, labels) for Docker
        id: meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@v5.5.0
        with:
          images: openhaus/backend
      
      - name: Build and push Docker image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v5.1.0
        with:
          context: .
          file: ./Dockerfile
          push: true
          tags:  openhaus/backend:nightly
          labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Secrets are not available to `pull_request` triggers. It's a security feature, since anyone could change the contents of the workflow and exfiltrate your secrets by simply submitting a Pull Request.

> Due to the dangers inherent to automatic processing of PRs, GitHub’s standard pull_request workflow trigger by default prevents write permissions and secrets access to the target repository. However, in some scenarios such access is needed to properly process the PR. To this end the pull_request_target workflow trigger was introduced.

See:

- https://securitylab.github.com/research/github-actions-preventing-pwn-requests

Even though the `pull_request_target` trigger is available, it's *VERY DANGAROUS*. Please read the above article carefully.

Comment: Have read it and understood that a attacker could reveal the secrets when a simple "echo/print" is done in the workflow. Not as easy as i thought. Do you think its safe with the condition `&& github.event.pull_request.merged == true` or should i include a pr review check? What i wonder right know: Even if i have such checks, and the attacker modifies the workflow and remove them/put the malicious code, do i not have the same scenario/security risk? Or would it just for the first pr/merge till the new workflow file is in place? Hope i could clarify what i mean, Englisch is not my native lang.

Comment: The new workflow with access to secrets won't work until after merge. So you can still catch the potential security problem in review. It of course depends on which workflows they modify. Personally I would not normally accept changes to the workflow file from any PR. Allowing people to push a docker container into your registry unchecked is also pretty dangerous. It would allow the attacker to sneak in all manner of tools and exploits.

Having such a condition would not help, because people can simply remove the condition. Or echo the secrets earlier in the workflow.

Comment: The exfiltration could also be hidden in a npm package update or a change in some build script or node build script in the package.json. And instead of echo they could curl or wget or even dnslookup to send the secret to an outside source.